# How to move my store from localhost to motifz.com.pk

Tags: magento-1.7, database

I have completed the development process now I want to move my Magento store files from local-host (local) to (live) www.motifz.com.pk but I don't know what changes should need to made in database and Magento files.

Also could you guide me on what is the best way to add products to the store on local and on live?

Answer (score 2):

Moving a Magento store to another domain is actually very straight forward.  Just copy the fileset across and import the database.  Once that's done change the `base_url` entries in the `core_config_data` table:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%base_url';
```

in PMA or similar and change the relevant entries to the new domain.  Also worth checking a `cookie_domain` is not set as this will cause issues if it's wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%cookie_domain';
```

and update or even remove the relevant entries.

The last thing you will need to do is update the database connection details in the file `app/etc/local.xml`.

From here you will want to clear all cache and sessions by deleting the contents of the `var/cache/` and `var/session/` folders, clear your browser cookies and that literally is all you need to do.